# h:commandbutton invoking bean method only once that redirects to a different page in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jsp, jsf, jsf-2

I am using jsf h:commandButton . My Requirement is that based on value of Button , i have to handle the action . I have used following

```
<h:commandButton id="raisecm" render="@all " styleClass="btn btn-primary" execute="@this"
                             value="#{scenarioConfigurationMB.status}"
                             actionListener="#{scenarioConfigurationMB.createPatchingCMTicket()}"
                             onclick="if(this.value=='Edit Ticket'){this.form.target='_blank';}">

            </h:commandButton>
```

Here status can be either "Create Ticket" or "Edit Ticket". If status is "Create Ticket" i have to create a ticket in Backing Bean method "createPatchingCMTicket" , otherwise if the status is "Edit Ticket" i have to return open a page in new tab showing its details.

Method in backing bean is as:

```
  public String createPatchingCMTicket() {
    System.out.println("***********************Ticket ID"+ ticketId);
    ticketId="123";
    System.out.println("Checking Status of  CM Ticket For Patching ......");
     if (status.equals("Edit Ticket")) {
        System.out.println("*********Status is \"Edit Ticket\"");
        try{
            ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
            externalContext.redirect("/cm/view_ticket.xhtml?changeTicketId="+ticketId);
              } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Redirection Failed........`enter code here`..................***************");
            throw new FacesException("Redirection failed......");
        }

        System.out.println("********Redirected........");
        return null;
    }

    System.out.println("Creating Ticket.............***********");
        log.info("Creating CM Ticket For Patching ......");

  //Code for Creating Ticket
```

}

If I am using above concept in h:commandButton , if the status is "Edit Ticket" , it is working fine and redirecting to the other url in new tab but only for first click  and if I again click on 'Edit Ticket' it is opening the same base page in new tab and not redirecting to new page.

I have struggled a lot to resolve this unexpected issue.
Kindly help.

Comment: Please add your status generation method.

Comment: @HatemAlimam : status is just a string variable , for that getter and setter are present in backing bean. "status" represents the value printed on the command button.

Comment: @learner...first thing first. `<h:commandButton>` doesn't have inbuilt `ajax` capability. So it doesn't have `render`and `execute` attributes.So, Please go thorough documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/) first and get to know `API` existed in the documentation